# 64-bit .NET C++ project compiles with 32-bit MSBuild/CL.exe but fails to find corecrt.h with 64-bit MSBuild.exe/CL.exe

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, cl.exe

I have a small vcxproj. It is 64-bit only, uses v141 platform toolset, and was using Windows SDK 8.1, I have also tried using Windows SDK 10.0.16299.0 to see if that made any difference, but it didn't.

Previously, the project was being compiled using 32-bit MSBuild, and working fine. Recently I tried compiling using 64-bit MSBuild. The command line call to the C++ compiler is identical (including all include directories), apart from the compiler it calls is

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\bin\HostX64\x64\CL.exe`

instead of

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\bin\HostX86\x64\CL.exe"`

(changed HostX86 -> Hostx64). This results in the following error message:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\crtdefs.h(10, 0): error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'corecrt.h': No such file or directory`

I am at a loss as to what the problem could be; it's using the same include paths, and the same Windows SDK. I don't see why the bitness of the compiler should affect whether it can find a header file when the target architecture hasn't changed!

The machine this is running on has Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise, Windows SDK 8.1 and Windows SDK 10.0.16299.0 installed.

Slightly wider context: this came up as part of updating our build dependencies. We use Invoke-Build to run the build, and as of 3.6.3 it started detecting 64-bit MSBuild installations, and using them by default. I could, of course, simply pin to 32-bit MSBuild, but I would like to get to the bottom of why the bitness of the build tools makes a difference in this situation.

Comment: "Invoke-Build" sounds like a magic wand that lost its magic.  Using the wrong CL.exe version isn't very different from using the wrong include paths, corecrt.h should always be easy to find since it is part of the universal crt.  File a bug with the project or avoid wands.

Comment: Invoke-Build is correctly calling MSBuild (just the 64-bit version rather than the 32-bit version). MSBuild is calling a different, but I believe still correct, CL.exe. Upgrading Invoke-Build is merely the reason I ended up looking into the difference between 32-bit and 64-bit MSBuild/CL.exe.